# Odds Fantasy game

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

There are 8 groups:
A has 6 players
B has 8 players
C has 10 players
D,E,F,G,H have 12 players

Every player will accrue points in a football match.

If every player had the same expectation of points, what would be the odds for guessing correctly:

The top player of all 8 groups
The top player of 7/8 groups
The top player of 6/8 groups
The top player of 5/8 groups?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just can't remember the formula to be used for every case. I know that for getting correct the top player of 8 groups, the odds would be: 1/6*1/8*1/10*1/12*1/12*1/12*1/12*1/12

Comment: For 7/8 I can also obtain the odds, but doing it "manually" i.e. doing the same process as above with the 8 different combinations for arriving at 7/8 correct players

Comment: Obviously for 6/8 and 5/8 doing it manually is not worth it, so finding out the correct formula would be really helpful

Comment: I suggest you make a new post that would include the info that you gave me in the comments while deleting this post. People here want to see that at least you've tried the problem (and you obviously did) so including that extra info will surely bring you an informative answer